# AngularJs windows phone 8 app. Angular js dosn't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework

I try to build a windows 8 universal app vith visual studio and cordova. If i test it i connect my phone with usb, and run in visual studio 2015 community, with debug option on windows 8 universal app, on my device directly. (If i choose window phone 8 option it do't work)

If i test it on android, im using android emulator.

First i try Mobile angular Ui, than Ionic framework
Both of them using AngularJs.

On android emulator, the demo app of each and my code running fine. But on windows phone i have some problems.

I have windows phone device, so first i want to bulid windows phone version of my app.

Im including this: https://github.com/ClemMakesApps/winstore-jscompat
And download all the needed js (angularjs, or for ioinc framework just the ionic.bundle.js), so i don't have online js files.

Winstore jscompact solve me the "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to add dynamic content. A script attempted to inject dynamic content, or elements previously modified dynamically, that might be unsafe." problem.

But it still don't work. Becouse now i have another error. (Same for mobilangularui and ionic)

JavaScript runtime error: 'angular' is undefined

Im using the default demo files for both framework.

Here it is for ionic: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs

Someone can help me to run ionic framework starter tabs template on windows phone please?

Comment: do u still have this problem?